# Sort structure on a string key with accented characters

Tags: sorting, go, data-structures, non-ascii-characters

I recently stumbled upon a problem trying to sort a structure on a key containing french strings. The classical `sort.SliceStable` doesn't take the accented characters into account correctly according the french rules for alphabetical sort.

Thankfully, the [collate](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/collate#Collator.Key) package does that correctly, but I couldn't find a way to directly use that package on structures without using it combined with the `sort.SliceStable` function.

This what I came up with that seems to work correctly:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"

    "golang.org/x/text/collate"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

type SortFr struct {
    Order int
    Fr    string
}

func main() {

    // the int SortFr.Order reflects the correct french sort order
    s := []SortFr{
        SortFr{2, "côte"},
        SortFr{0, "cote"},
        SortFr{5, "coter"},
        SortFr{1, "coté"},
        SortFr{4, "cotée"},
        SortFr{3, "côté"},
    }

    // incorrect sort order 
    sort.SliceStable(s, func(i, j int) bool {
        return s[i].Fr < s[j].Fr
    })
    fmt.Println(s)

    // correct sort order
    cl := collate.New(language.French)
    sort.SliceStable(s, func(i, j int) bool {
        return cl.CompareString(s[i].Fr, s[j].Fr) == -1
    })
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

This code returns:

```
[{0 cote} {5 coter} {1 coté} {4 cotée} {2 côte} {3 côté}]
[{0 cote} {1 coté} {2 côte} {3 côté} {4 cotée} {5 coter}]
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this on large structures?

Comment: The "most efficient way" is to not sort at all. If you ask whether sort.Slice is less efficient than sort.Sort: Yes. use sort.Sort. Collation is slow and you cannot do anything against it. Except: Add  an extra field `Accentless`, copy Fr to it while remove all accents and sort  on that one. This won't give your french collation o rder but mightb e  much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting is based on a less function which simply calls `cl.CompareString()`. What simpler do you wish for? You have to tell somehow / somewhere you want to sort based on the `Fr` field, and this is how you can do that.

[`sort.SliceStable()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SliceStable) is generic in a way that it can sort any slice. For this it has to use reflection under the hood, which is slower than a solution that doesn't have to resort to reflection. So if you want to sort a large slice, implementing [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) is profitable.

```
var cl = collate.New(language.French)

type FrSlice []SortFr

func (s FrSlice) Len() int           { return len(s) }
func (s FrSlice) Less(i, j int) bool { return cl.CompareString(s[i].Fr, s[j].Fr) < 0 }
func (s FrSlice) Swap(i, j int)      { s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] }
```

And then using it:

```
s := []SortFr{
    // ...
}

sort.Stable(FrSlice(s))
```

Also note that [`sort.Sort()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) may be somewhat faster than [`sort.Stable()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Stable), as the former does not have to guarantee the original order of equal elements. So use `sort.Sort()` if keeping original order of equal elements is not a requirement.

Comment: Just ran a benchmark and `sort.Sort()` on a interface type is indeed the fastest but by a small margin compared to  `sort.Slice()` on a custom comparator.  `BenchmarkSortInterface-8 325581813 ns/op 87795264 B/op 629477 allocs/op
BenchmarkSortSlice-8     329308126 ns/op 87795288 B/op 629479 allocs/op`